# Jenkins Upgrade to LTS 2.249.1 - Side-bar panel menu missing

Tags: jenkins

Please advice, recently i have upgraded my jenkins from 2.190.3 to 2.249.1, the exception is that the side panel menu is missing in all GUI, jenkins is working properly am able to build trigger without any problem.  [Am able to see menu from Navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPp2D.png)  and [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB8Hf.png)

But it's missing from all the pages

[Missing from Jenkins Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLMpJ.png)

[From all the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR2PA.png)

Please advice.